# Is there a chance to lose all your enchantments when enchanting an item?

Tags: torchlight-2

In the first game, there was only one enchanter in the game who could enchant your items as many times as you want if you had the money and were brave enough to chance at losing all your enhancements.  The more you enchant an item, the more likely that he'd screw it up and you lose your enchantments on that item forever.

Fast forward to the next game, you have a limited amount of enchantments that can be applied to an item but you now have the option to remove enchantments for some money.

**Is there a chance that attempting to enchant an item *now* can remove all enchantments on your item?**

I've saved up enough money to enchant my best weapons so I will be enchanting as much as I can.  I'd just hate to lose everything.

Comment: I haven't played Torchlight 1 and I was confused that the enchanter always says something like `Fortune favors you` when you enchant an item in Torchlight 2, giving me the impression the enchant *could* fail, but this explains it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Enchanting is very different from what was found in Torchlight 1.  Enchanting adds magical properties that can also be removed (deliberately) by an enchanter.  But enchanting can no longer wipe an item; that is, enchanting cannot affect existing stats in any way.  The removal mechanic exists so you can spend gold to get an item "just right".

Comment: And for clarity's sake: no, attempting to add enchants cannot wipe your current enchants **nor** the base stats of the item. All a failure will do is consume your gold.

Comment: "Enchanting can no longer wipe an item".