# Does Torchlight 2 have a chance of disenchant like there was in the first Torchlight?

Tags: torchlight-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a chance to lose all your enchantments when enchanting an item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86347/is-there-a-chance-to-lose-all-your-enchantments-when-enchanting-an-item)

Having an uber-enchanted item become disenchanted was the most irritating aspect of Torchlight 1.  After a quick Googling, I've found nothing that suggests Torchlight 2 has a disenchant chance and I've enchanted a few items up to 4 times without problems, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything.

**Edit:**  Ahhhh... how funny this should happen.  I decided to push the limit on this weapon one more time and now a message says "Max enchantments" in the enchantment window and I am not able to enchant the weapon further.  I am guessing the guys at Runic realized their disenchant logic from the first game was a bit harsh and decided to implement a enchantment cap instead.  Still, it's possible that there is a disenchant chance.  Anyone who can confirm this and cite a source will get best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot disenchant items from trying to enchant them. They (thankfully) removed this aspect in the game. You can remove the enchantments you paid to put but it removes them all.

For example, say you find a pistol with +4 mana. You pay an enchanter twice to add enchantments and get +4 electric damage and +2 strength. You decide you don't want those so you pay him to disenchant it. The +4 electric damage and +2 strength are removed, the original +4 mana stays.

Some enchanters can only do a max of 2 enchantments, like the enchanter you can get in town. You may run into other enchanters in dungeons or on the overworld which can do 3 or 4.

Check out [this enchanting article on the wiki](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Enchanting_%28T2%29) for more information